# Автоматический a href

Tags: javascript, html

У менять есть блок `<div>http://link.com http://link.com http://link.com </div>`
Как сделать чтоб ссылки стали автоматически кликабельны, то есть: `<div><a href="http://link.com">http://link.com</a>`